# Java swing: How to solve this problem when I change my background color in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing

1. When changing the background color of JOptionPane it is not possible to change the background color of the text as shown in the image?!

The image that contains the problem

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEVuF.png]

---

and

2. Also, how can I change the background color of the OK button and the font color??

---

****Note**: that I have tried many solutions, but none of them work.**

this is code:

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.buttonFont", new Font("Arial", PLAIN, 30));
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("<html><b style=\"color:RED; font-size:20px;\">login successful</b></html>", 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,         
    ChangeIconJoptionPane("/photo/icons8_Done_70px.png", 60, 60));

    getComponents(pane);
    pane.setBackground(new Color(32, 139, 223));
    JDialog jd = pane.createDialog(this, "Success");
    jd.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"that I have tried many solutions, but none of them work."* Try creating a couple more GUIs, then a hundred more. By that time you will likely have: a) worked out how to do it with the `UIManager` or a custom PLAF, and also b) that users typically prefer a robust, no nonsense, intuitive GUI to one that uses bold, distinct colors.

Comment: Create your own custom dialog if you want full control of the fonts/colors etc. The JOptionPane is only designed to be customized by the data displayed.

Comment: @camickr
 Thanks, Can you provide a source with which to work custom dialog?

Comment: You create a custom dialog the same way you create a custom JFrame. You create a JDialog and add components to the dialog.

Comment: Thank you all, I have benefited from your advice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOptionPane is made up of many components.  You will need to set the background for all of them.

Here is an easy way to traverse an entire component tree:

```
private static Stream<Component> walk(Component root) {
    Stream<Component> stream = Stream.of(root);

    if (root instanceof Container) {
        Component[] children = ((Container) root).getComponents();
        stream = Stream.concat(
            Arrays.stream(children).flatMap(c -> walk(c)), stream);
    }

    return stream;
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(
        "<html><b style=\"color:RED; font-size:20px;\">login successful</b></html>", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,         
        ChangeIconJoptionPane("/photo/icons8_Done_70px.png", 60, 60));

    Color background = new Color(32, 139, 223);
    walk(pane).forEach(c -> c.setBackground(background));
}
```

**However…** in some look-and-feels, it is not possible to change the background color of a JButton.  The system look-and-feels for Windows and Mac will ignore a JButton’s background property, and will always render the button using the system settings.

The most reliable way to customize the OK button is to create the button yourself, and pass it as an option value to the JOptionPane:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

    Font font = okButton.getFont();
    font = font.deriveFont(font.getSize2D() * 1.5f);
    okButton.setFont(font);

    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(
        "<html><b style=\"color:RED; font-size:20px;\">login successful</b></html>", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,         
        ChangeIconJoptionPane("/photo/icons8_Done_70px.png", 60, 60),
        new Object[] { okButton });

    okButton.addActionListener(e -> pane.setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION));

    Color background = new Color(32, 139, 223);
    walk(pane).forEach(c -> c.setBackground(background));
}
```

Comment: @VAR Thank you, it worke beautifully, but  how can I change the background color of the OK button and Font size and color??

Comment: @MuhammadSalem Updated question with how to customize OK button’s font.

Comment: @VAR Yes, it works beautifully, but I just can't change the background color of the OK button?

Comment: As I said above: The system look-and-feels for Windows and Mac will ignore a JButton’s background property, and will always render the button using the system settings.  Stack Overflow has many discussions of this.

Comment: @VAR Thank you very much for all this valuable information.